# Async result empty but data exists in response

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume a webservice with async methods. I have used it's WSDL to create a client and calling the metod like this:

```
public static GetStockResponse GetResult()
    {
        var client = new ServiceSoapClient();
        var inItems = new ArrayOfItemNo();
        inItems.Add(new ItemNoRow { ItemNo = "0000001350" });
        Task<GetStockResponse> task = client.GetStockAsync(inItems, "034");
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }
```

In fiddler I can see the call with status 200

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <s:Body>
<GetStockRequest xmlns="http://www.unikum.se/pws"
                 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ItemNo>
    <ItemNoRow>
      <ItemNo>0000001350</ItemNo>
    </ItemNoRow>
  </ItemNo>
  <StoreID>034</StoreID>
</GetStockRequest>
```

And the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <soap:Body>
<GetStockResponse xmlns="http://www.unikum.se/pws">
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <ItemNo>0000001350</ItemNo>
      <DeliveryTimeText>4-6 veckor</DeliveryTimeText>
      <DeliveryDays>42</DeliveryDays>
      <Stores>
        <Store>
          <StoreID>034</StoreID>
          <NotInERP>N</NotInERP>
          <InStockQty>2</InStockQty>
          <InShowRoom>N</InShowRoom>
        </Store>
      </Stores>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</GetStockResponse>
```

But the result of the task (task.Result) is empty. It is a GetStockResponse but all values is null.

Why? Everything seems correct or doesn't it?

Comment: Does the equivalent synchronous code work? Note that you're not really using the asynchrony here anyway, given your call to `Wait()`...

Comment: No it doesn't. The regular code looks like this: var result = client.GetStock(inItems, "034", out outItems, out stores, out outStores); but all out parameters is empty. The response from the service is still ok and the same as the result above. I believe that the error might be based on that the WSDL information gives another structure than the service in reality returns. It's not my service but is that possible? To have a WSDL information not honored in the actual result?

Comment: Maybe - not sure. But I'd definitely get the synchronous form working first... maybe get in contact with the service owner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some more testing with some other methods provided by the service owner clearly indicated that they did not follow the response structure defined in their own WSDL. I could see that in a simpler test where they partially followed the WSDL structure I got correct values back on those specific properties but not on those that differed. So now I could more clearly point to the error and return with  "Please fix this, or else" response to the service provider.